# How to copy a date from one Excel sheet to another sheet with specific format?

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet1 with dates at column L9 till L15.
The dates must be saved to another sheet2 at column L3 till L9.
I am using the formula:

```
=IF('Sheet1'!L10="","",TEXT('Sheet1'!L10;"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

Comment: I am not understanding the problem, can you give examples of what it is doing that is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **consistent field separator**.  Either:

```
=IF('Sheet1'!L10="","",TEXT('Sheet1'!L10,"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```

or

```
=IF('Sheet1'!L10="";"";TEXT('Sheet1'!L10;"yyyy-mm-dd"))
```